# Exception handling print statements not working, but error types are?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

My code is below. The exception handling itself works, but I am unable to get the error messages specified to print.

```
import numpy as np
def compute_circle_area(r):
    try:
        if type(r) == 'complex' :
          raise(TypeError('Argument is complex'))
        elif r < 0 :
          raise(ValueError('Argument < 0'))
        elif type(r) == str :
          raise(TypeError('Argument is wrong type'))
  
        a = np.pi * r * r

    except ValueError as ve:
      print("Value Error", ve)
    except TypeError as te:
      print("Type Error", te)
    else:
      print('Argument works, solution is: ', a)
    finally:
      print("Let's continue")

print(compute_circle_area(2.1))
print(compute_circle_area(2+1j))
print(compute_circle_area(-2.1))
print(compute_circle_area('radius'))
```

Comment: The value of `type(r)` is a type, not a string, so `type(r) == 'complex'` will never be true. Use `== complex`

Comment: I can see errors being printed, it sounds like your environment is the issue

Comment: you should check `traceback.print_exc()`

Comment: The printing should work fine. There are some other issues with your code, e.g. you should use `isinstance(r, complex)` to check whether r is of type complex and you should first check whether r is a string before comparing it to 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print just the error message, you have to print the args attribute, not the error. Else, it will give you the whole representation of the error.